# Java comparing a created Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I am going over the basics of creating a Linked List and need to find out if these two are equal before and after a replace. The replace is working properly as I have print statements in my main method to check, but I am somehow not correctly comparing these two after the replace. The problem is in my equals method.

```
    public boolean replace(int index, Object newEntry) {
        boolean isSuccessful = true;
        Node nodeToReplace = getNode(index);
        getNode(index).data = newEntry;

        if(newEntry == nodeToReplace){
            isSuccessful = false;
        }
        return isSuccessful;
    } // end replace
    /** Task: Determines whether two lists are equal.
     * @param other object that contains the other linked list
     * @return true if two lists have the same length and all
     * entries are equal, or false if not */
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        MyLinkedList aList = (MyLinkedList)other;
        boolean isEqual = true; // result of comparison of lists
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        Node aListNode = firstNode;

        while ((currentNode != null)){
            if (currentNode.data == aListNode.data) {
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
                aListNode = aListNode.next;
            }
            else
                isEqual = false;
        }
        return isEqual;
    } // end equals
    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return length == 0;
    }

    // @return an string with all entries in the list
    public String toString() {
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        String s = new String();
        while (currentNode != null) {
            s += currentNode.data + " ";
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        return s;
    }
    private Node getNode(int index) {
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        // traverse the list to locate the desired node
        for (int counter = 0; counter < index; counter++)
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        return currentNode;
    } // end getNode
    private class Node {
        private Object data; // data portion
        private Node next; // link to next node

        private Node(Object dataPortion) {
            data = dataPortion;
            next = null;
        } // end constructor
        private Node(Object dataPortion, Node nextNode) {
            data = dataPortion;
            next = nextNode;
        } // end constructor
        private void setData(Object dataPortion) {
            data = dataPortion;
        } // end setData
        private Object getData() {
            return data;
        } // end getData
        private void setNextNode(Node nextNode) {
            next = nextNode;
        } // end setNextNode
        private Node getNextNode() {
            return next;
        } // end getNextNode
    } // end Node
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it always saying they're equal?

You're initializing `currentNode` and `aListNode` with the same node:

```
Node currentNode = firstNode;
Node aListNode = firstNode;
```

You probably want this:

```
Node currentNode = firstNode;
Node aListNode = aList.firstNode;
```

Once you fix that, you'll find it runs forever. You should `return false` once you realize the two lists are not equal. Then you can get rid of `isEqual`. Right now you set `isEqual` to false, but you never leave the loop.

Comment: Yes it is constantly saying they are equal, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In you `equals` function, you're starting both `currentNode` and `aListNode` on the same place.

I believe you want to initialize `currentNode` to the old list and `aListNode` to the new one, or vice-versa in order to compare them both, otherwise you'll always get a true return from the function